# Graph Theory-forest and its components

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a forest with two components and at least four vertices. Is it true that G has at least four leaves?

---

[image]

the graph is which is I mentioned you

Comment: Exactly how are you defining *leaf*?

Comment: A leaf is a vertex of degree 1

Comment: Consider an isolated vertex and a chain of $3$ vertices: `*   *---*---*`

Comment: for being forest, all of whose connected components must be trees

Comment: By the definitions with which I’m familiar, that *is* a forest: both components *are* trees, since both are connected and acyclic.

Comment: yes,it is true.However,the example will not be a tree

Comment: I don’t understand your last comment. The example that I gave is a graph with two components, each of which is a tree, so the example is a forest with two components. It also has $4$ vertices and only $2$ leaves.

Comment: It is clear now.Thank you so much..

Comment: You’re welcome. By the way, if each of the trees has at least two vertices, the result is true, since every tree with more than one vertex has at least two leaves.

Comment: if a tree is like that *--* ,the leaf will be 1 or 2?

Comment: If a tree has more than one vertex, it must have at least two leaves: a graph with exactly one vertex of degree $1$ always contains a cycle, so it can never be a tree.